# Multivariate normal/change of variables in integral ("derivative of change is change of derivative"?)

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution, change-of-variable, hermite-polynomials

Let us consider the following integral:
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |D^{\alpha} P(x;\Sigma)| dx,$$
where $P(x;\Sigma)=((2\pi)^d |\Sigma|)^{-1/2}\exp(-\frac{1}{2}x^T\Sigma^{-1}x)$ denotes the density of a multivariate normal vector with $\vec{0}$ mean and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Here, $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_d)$ is a multiindex and $D^\alpha=\frac{\partial^{\alpha_1}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}}\cdots \frac{\partial^{\alpha_d}}{\partial x_d^{\alpha_d}}$ the derivative operator.

Consider the Cholesky decomposition of $\Sigma = LL^T$. Then if I am correct, the change of variables $L^{-1}x=y$ (or $x=Ly$) will transform the density $P$ in a standard multivariate normal density. We know that the Jacobian is $|dx/dy|=|L|=|\Sigma|^{1/2}$. Altogether,

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |D^{\alpha} P(x;\Sigma)| dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |D^{\alpha} P(y;I)| dy.$$
The last integrand is nothing else than: $\prod_{j=1}^d|H_{\alpha_j}(y_j)p(y_j;1)|$, where $p$ are the one-dimensional Gaussian densities with mean 0 and variance 1.

Finally,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |D^{\alpha} P(x;\Sigma)| dx = \prod_{j=1}^d E\left[|H_{\alpha_j}(Z)|\right],$$
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Is this reasoning correct? Is there any "fixable" flaw in the computations? The whole thing looks too easy to me... I don't think it is correct because the LHS depends on $\Sigma$ while the RHS doesn't. Where is the mistake and in such case can one work out the expressions to get something similar?

I appreciate any help in this matter. Thanks a lot guys! :)

Comment: Think you also need to consider the change of variables in your derivative operator. Should cause the dependence on $\Sigma$, which was cancelled by the change of integral area element, to reappear.

Comment: What do you mean? How would that be written/taken into account? Does the final simplification look similar to the one proposed above?

Comment: I mean that in your change of variables from $x \mapsto y$ you have just said $D^{\alpha}f(x) = D^{\alpha}f(y)$, which isn't the case - I'm not particularly optimistic a nice simplification will take place, the multivariate hermite polynomials corresponding to general covariance $\Sigma$ are treated as their own distinct objects in asymptotic expansions of multivariate density functions

Comment: Yes now I understand! of course, it would have been easier to detect this mistake if $D^\alpha$ was denoted $D_x^\alpha$. I see. What a pity then! Then it means that: $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|D^\alpha P(x;\Sigma)|dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|H_\alpha (x;\Sigma) P(x;\Sigma)|dx$, where $H_\alpha$ is the multivarite Hermite polynomial. Do you know how one can get rid of $\Sigma$ inside the polynomial or if there are polynomial bounds of $H_\alpha$ w.r.t. $\Sigma$ or its entries? :D

Comment: There isn't one that I know of but I will have a look/think about it - again my pessimism occurs because if it was straightforward to represent the multivariate hermite polynomials as some kind of compact product of the standard hermite polynomials I think it would make certain multivariate expansions more popular than they are - but that is hardly a proof that it can't be done, just a hunch

Comment: Exactly... I understand. Well, for me it would be good enough to have some rough estimates since I actually have an integral over a compact $K$ set and not $\mathbb{R}^d$ but anyways.. these Hermite polynomials are really tiresome.. :)